# Rstudio: Error unexpected symbol in line that has no discernible errors

Tags: r, error-handling

```
glm(So0i1l~Infe0t+1ge+OS,family=binomial(link = logit))
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "glm(So0i1l~Infe0t+1ge"

```
 glm(So0i1l~Infe0t+1ge+OS) family=binomial(link = logit))
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "glm(So0i1l~Infe0t+1ge"

I have gone through this code multiple times and anytime I try to do this analysis i get the same error. I've tried formatting in multiple ways but I haven't found any answers to my problem anywhere.

Comment: You need `cbind` or just close parens well ie `glm(So0i1l~Infe0t+1ge+OS,family=binomial(link = logit))` You need a `data` argument too otherwise `glm` won't find these variables. You should use an IDE eg RStudio to make it easier to see such unmatched parens.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by parens and how i would format a cbind? The ie is identical to one of my attempts and I still receive the same  error.

Comment: parens is parentheses(was too lazy to type it in full). Using `cbind` will depend on what type of model you want to use, it just "binarises" columns. An [example using cbind](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259502/in-using-the-cbind-function-in-r-for-a-logistic-regression-on-a-2-times-2-t).

Comment: Thank you that worked out well, now i just got to figure out the next error lol :/

Comment: your variable `1ge` shouldnt be named that way. R doesn't like variables that start with a number. try without that variable and see if it works. if it does, then rename that variable and it should be fine